# Jquery toggle add classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a jquery function the first part works however the second part with the same logic does not. In the second half i want the the classes to be switched again. please let me know if you need more of the code. New to Jquery. Thanks

```
<script>
</div>
<button class="button GBP" id="conv_currency">Change to £GBP</button>
</div>

    $(".GBP").click(function(){
    if (document.getElementById("conv_currency").className == "button GBP") {
        document.getElementById("conv_currency").innerHTML = "Change to $USD";
        $(".GBP").removeClass("GBP").addClass("USD");
    }
    });

$(".USD").click(function(){
   if(document.getElementById("conv_currency").className == "button USD") {
        document.getElementById("conv_currency").innerHTML = "Change to £GBP";
       $(".USD").removeClass("USD").addClass("GBP");
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: use event delegation for jquery use `.on()`

Comment: Why you are mixing vanilla js and jquery?

Comment: Also, when you are using jQuery, you can make your code much more concise using jQuery instead of plain javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
$(document).on('click',".GBP",function(){
    if (document.getElementById("conv_currency").className == "button GBP") {
        document.getElementById("conv_currency").innerHTML = "Change to $USD";
        $(".GBP").removeClass("GBP").addClass("USD");
    }
    });

$(document).on('click',".USD",function(){
   if(document.getElementById("conv_currency").className == "button USD") {
        document.getElementById("conv_currency").innerHTML = "Change to £GBP";
       $(".USD").removeClass("USD").addClass("GBP");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>
<button class="button GBP" id="conv_currency">Change to £GBP</button>
</div>
```

1. Use event delegation for jquery use `.on()`

Comment: Wow super quick and exactly what im looking for thanks. Havent discovered the .on() function in my jquery learning yet. Appreciate the help

Comment: happy to help.. happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 1):

Simply try with [`toggleClass`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiMrJaoqPvTAhXLv48KHXc3ALsQFggmMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ftoggleclass%2F&usg=AFQjCNFtqAo0d_GtKfi5qu8SeVyUo5vKIw&sig2=d0jyU6y8-LHgF2sVTxoLmQ) and [`Conditional (ternary) Operator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)  .Its same as your code working

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
$(this).html($(this).hasClass("GBP") ? "Change to $USD" : "Change to £GBP").toggleClass("USD GBP")
console.log($(this).attr('class'))
});
```

```css
.USD {color: red;}
.GBP {color: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="button GBP" id="conv_currency">Change to £GBP</button>
```

Comment: `toggleClass` is by far the best solution imho

Answer (score 0):

Check the following line:

```
$(".GBP").removeClass("GBP").addClass("USD");
```

by this you are changing the class dynamically, so to deal with dynamic class use `.on()` like:

```
$(document).on('click',".GBP",function(){
```

**Note:** `$(document).on()` works for dynamic html also.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".button").click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass("USD")){ 
      $(this).text("Change to £GBP").removeClass('USD').addClass("GBP"); 
  }else  if($(this).hasClass("GBP")){ 
      $(this).text("Change to $USD").removeClass('GBP').addClass("USD"); 
  }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>
<button class="button GBP" id="conv_currency">Change to £GBP</button>
</div>
```

Check the current class and change the text and class name

Answer (score 0):

Though the solution is already provided, but alternatively you can try to target the `button` class instead of `GBP` or `USD`.

```js
$(".button").click(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('GBP')) {
    $(this).removeClass('GBP').addClass('USD').text('Change to £USD')
  } else if ($(this).hasClass('USD')) {
    $(this).removeClass('USD').addClass('GBP').text('Change to $GBP')
  }
})
```

```css
.GBP {
  color: red;
}

.USD {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</div>
<button class="button GBP" id="conv_currency">Change to £GBP</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).on('click',".button",function(){
            $(this).toggleClass("GBP").toggleClass("USD");
            if($(this).text() == "Change to £GBP"){
                $(this).text("Change to USD");
            }
            else{
                $(this).text("Change to £GBP");
            }
        });

// OR you can also this

$(document).on('click',".button",function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("GBP").toggleClass("USD");
        if($(this).hasClass("USD")){
            $(this).text("Change to USD");
        }
        else{
            $(this).text("Change to £GBP");
        }
    });

//choices is yours
```

Comment: Some explanation why this fixes the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: you want when click on button first gbp will remove and usd will add. then you click on button gbp will added usd will be removed